# SQL Query: is 2nd clause filtered by 1st clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT users.id FROM sprints INNER JOIN users on (sprints.user_id = users.id )
WHERE sprints.user_id IN (1,2,3)
AND sprints.created_at BETWEEN x AND y
GROUP BY users.id HAVING COUNT(sprints.id) > 2
```

Does the `HAVING COUNT(sprints.id) > 2` part refer to having >2 sprints **that were created at between x and y**? Or does it refer to just having 2 sprints **in general (regardless of creation date)**?

Or in other words, is the 2nd part of the query filtered down to the results of the first query? If not, how would I do that?

Comment: The `HAVING` clause is executed on the results returned from the query before it. In this case, since the query above it is only returning results where `sprints.created_at BETWEEN x AND y`, it will only operate on these results.

Comment: Yes, but, the "results" are user objects, not sprint objects. Therefore, even though the users are filtered down, does that mean that the sprints being considered in `count(sprints.id)` are only sprints that are between X and Y? Or in [simpler] words: couldn't it be saying `give me users that have sprints between x and y, that ALSO have more than 2 total sprints (but not necessarily 2 total sprints that were also created at between x and y)`?

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY is evaluated after applying the filters on the WHERE clauses.

Therefore at the time of GROUP'ING, the filter conditions

```
WHERE sprints.user_id IN (1,2,3)
AND sprints.created_at BETWEEN x AND y
```

are already applied.

Next step is evaluating the HAVING clause.

We got the GROUPED record set at this stage, after that the filter on the HAVING clause is applied

```
HAVING COUNT(sprints.id)>2
```

Edit: From the comments, the OP asks options on how to show up records that

- a) have sprints between times x and y
- b) have 2 sprints (but those 2 sprints don't necessarily need to
  be between x and y)

Here, the conditions need to be applied without the filter conditions. Therefore we first "conditionally" count by using a case expression as below.

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN sprints.created_at BETWEEN x AND y THEN 
                1 
       END)
```

This count expression "counts" if the sprints created_at date lies between x and y. The COUNT(*) column counts regardless of any condition.

Now that we have the two metrics, we filter the record set, to satisfy

Bring only records where we have "sprints between times x and y" AND "have 2 sprints"

```
   WHERE cnt_of_sprints_between_x_and_y >0
     AND cnt_of_sprints >0
```

Final query

```
  WITH DATA
        AS (
       SELECT users.id
              ,COUNT(CASE WHEN sprints.created_at BETWEEN x AND y THEN 
                                1 
                      END) as cnt_of_sprints_between_x_and_y
              ,COUNT(*) as cnt_of_sprints
         FROM sprints 
        INNER JOIN users 
           ON (sprints.user_id = users.id )
        WHERE sprints.user_id IN (1,2,3)
    GROUP BY users.id 
        )
  SELECT id
    FROM data
   WHERE cnt_of_sprints_between_x_and_y >0
     AND cnt_of_sprints >0
```

Comment: Ok, I think I understand... so in the original query, let's say that what I ACTUALLY wanted was "Give me all of the students who a) have sprints between times x and y, AND b) have 2 sprints (but those 2 sprints don't necessarily need to be between x and y). How would I rewrite it?

Comment: Also... just because the GROUP BY is "evaluated after applying the filters on the WHERE clauses" doesn't mean that inside of `COUNT(sprints.id)`, `sprints` refers to only the sprints created_at between x and y. To me, logically that seems to apply "of the students who have sprints created_at between x and y, now give me [from that subset] the students who have >2 sprints in general. No?

Comment: Exactly!. For the updated comments, i have modified my answer